# How can you know all factors < 10 of a number if you know the number modulo 2520?

Tags: number-theory

I read somewhere that we can determine which factors $< 10$ a number has if we know $x\pmod{2520}$.

I know that $2520$ is the smallest number that is divisible by all of the first $10$ digits, but how do you go from that to the assumption that you can find all factors $< 10$ of a number if you know the number $\pmod{2520}$? Are the factors $< 10$ of $x$ and $x\pmod{2520}$ the same?

Comment: The factors of x and x modulo are exactly the same because 2520 is divisible by all factors.  But I don't see how this helps you if you don't know the factors of x modulo.  Are we assuming finding the factors of x modulo is easy?  Then why are we assuming finding the factors of x is hard?

Comment: @fleablood If i have a large number, it's harder to go through it to find all it's factors < 10 than it is to simply get it's remainder modulo 2520 and look up the factors in an existing table (Plus i already have to do the modulo anyways, so this method means that i get the factors practically for free).

Comment: Okay, from a computation viewpoint it makes sense but from an abstract viewpoint it seemed.... an odd way of putting it.  But it is Tru that you can find the factors less than 10 by finding the factors x modulo 2520 as they will have 5he same factors less than 10.

Comment: @fleablood, the poster is probably asking for help understanding how to solve their programming contest problem: https://www.codechef.com/JULY16/problems/WORKCHEF.  That's probably why it sounds strange.

Comment: @D.W. It's pretty extreme to connect a very general algorithm for quickly evaluating factors of a number to a programming problem that may also require you to simply evaluate factors of a number.

Comment: Feel free to edit the question to include the context where you ran across this problem.  Remember, general Math.SE guidelines are that high-quality questions should include [context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9960/14578): why you want to solve this, in what situation you encountered this, what you tried.  Also, when you write "I read somewhere" it would be even better to link to exactly *where* you wrote it or cite your source.  See also [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1803/14578) for more good advice about how to write a high-quality question.

Comment: As far as my earlier comment, perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38232782/efficiently-evaluating-a-polynomial-with-fixed-constants-with-many-values#comment64042869_38232782) might explain why someone might guess that this question might be derived from an attempt to solve a live programming contest problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x\equiv y\pmod{2520}$, then for some integer $k$, $x=2520k+y$.  If $y$ and $2520$ share a common factor, $n$, then the right side of the equation is divisible by $n$.  Then the other side of the equation, $x$, must also be divisible by $n$.  So yes, the factors less than $10$ of both will be the same.

Comment: I'm confused.  If for some reason we can't determine the factors of x, why would we be able to determine the factors of y any easierly?

Comment: @fleablood The question asked was essentially if the factors of $y$ that are less than $10$ are the same factors of $x$ that are less than $10$.  As to why one might do this, it might be entirely possible that $x$ is too large to store in a computer's memory.  But a number less than $2520$ could be stored easily.

Comment: Hmmm... guess so but I found the statement rather odd.